# Electro sensitivity - is it a thing?

Tags: medical-science, psychology, alternative-medicine, electromagnetism

Recently, a coworker brought up electro sensitivity as something to consider when developing new communications technology.

**What little I have researched so far**

The [WHO](http://www.who.int/peh-emf/publications/facts/fs296/en/) claims that the majority of studies suggest it is a psychological disorder, with self proclaimed "sensitive" individuals being consistently unable to predict exposure.

[Powerwatch UK](http://www.powerwatch.org.uk/health/sensitivity.asp) claims it is still little understood and compares it to Photosensitive epilepsy.

**My question**

Maybe a professional from a related field could clear up whether there is still reasonable doubt about the effects of EMF on health. 
Or in more simple terms: Is it a thing?

Comment: First link is broken for me.

Comment: Sorry, am on my phone and somehow messed up. Should be fixed now! Thank you!

Comment: Anyway, this question is indeed a duplicate. Didn't find the previously asked question since I was looking for electro sensitivity. Didn't pop up somehow.